# how to use Group by with top count in MDX query

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have an example where we prepared query in sql for fetching appropriate results

SQL Query-

```
select partnerid,BrandDesc,ActualRetailValue
from
(
select DENSE_RANK() over (partition by partnerid order by sum(ActualRetailValue) desc) as rnk,
partnerid,BrandDesc,sum(ActualRetailValue) as ActualRetailValue
from JDASales
where partnerid in (693,77)
group by partnerid,BrandDesc
) as A
where rnk <=5
order by partnerid,rnk
```

Output -

[image]

I want this result with mdx query.Even tryout with this code

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Actual Retail Value]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [DimBrands].[Brand].[Brand].ALLMEMBERS
    * 
      TopCount
      (
          [DimPartners].[Partner].[Partner].ALLMEMBERS
        * 
          [DimSKU].[XXX Desc].[XXX Desc].ALLMEMBERS
       ,5
       ,[Measures].[Actual Retail Value]
      ) ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[DimPartners].[Partner].&[1275]} ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {[Dim Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2014-01-01T00:00:00]} ON COLUMNS
    FROM [SALES]
  )
)
WHERE 
  [Dim Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2014-01-01T00:00:00];
```

Comment: So what happened when you ran this code?  More detail needed.

Comment: It didnt work.
It shows top 5 records only. i want top 5 count by brands

Comment: Can you edit the question showing the actual output you get from the MDX?  Also, it's not clear in the question exactly what you want to group by.  Your SQL output can't possibly come from the SQL code you've posted, as it includes the SKUDesc column which isn't in the SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can amend the rows snippet to use the `GENERATE` function:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Actual Retail Value]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    GENERATE( 
     [DimBrands].[Brand].[Brand].ALLMEMBERS AS B
    , 
     TopCount(
          B.CURRENTMEMBER
         *[DimPartners].[Partner].[Partner].ALLMEMBERS
         *[DimSKU].[XXX Desc].[XXX Desc].ALLMEMBERS
       ,5
       ,[Measures].[Actual Retail Value]
      )
    ) ON ROWS
...
...
```

This functions usage is detailed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145526.aspx